# Self Quadratic Phase Coupling || What does it really tell us?

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, phase

I am working on a beginner kind of project, and after processing some data and plotting a lot of *bispectrum* plots, I found out that a lot of them had peaks on the diagonal fx = fy (where fi denotes frequency along the i-axis). An example graph is the following:

[image]

**That's what we call self QPC but I don't really understand the concept around it**. In some signal processing lectures I had, we've seen examples on QPC, but the peaks were not on the diagonal and that meant that there's a third phase component equal to the sum (or the sub) of those 2 phase components where the peak is (that is φ3 = φ1 + φ2 or φ1 - φ2).
Correct me if I am wrong, after all, I am just a student!